# Trying to run sklearn on a loop and store predictions in a dataframe

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

**My problem**

I've been working for some time on an ML algorithm which predicts redshifts of galaxies based on magnitudes. An MWE here:

https://pastebin.com/G19Qx2Yj

The MWE is a self-contained version of my full code, which is more complex, but this is as close as I can get it to the actual script.

In lines 120-122, I add the predictions as a column to `X_test`. This works as intended.

**What I'm trying to achieve**

On each iteration through the loop, I'm trying to add another column to `X_test`, labelled `X_test1`, `X_test2`, `X_test3`, etc. so I can calculate the average of all of them.

**What I've tried**

- I've tried using

  X_test['z_spec'] = y_test
  X_test['z_phot'+str(i)] = y_pred

but this ends up just recording y_pred from the final run.

- I've also tried moving `train_test_split` to line 102, before the loop, so that I'm not reinitialising `X_test` on each iteration, but this returns an error:

  ```
    ValueError: Input 0 of layer "sequential_15" is incompatible with the layer: expected shape=(None, 5), found shape=(None, 8)
  ```
- I've tried making a new dataframe to store the predictions:

```
z_df = pd.DataFrame([])
z_df ['z_spec'] = y_test
z_df ['z_phot'+str(i)] = y_pred
z_df ['delta_z'] = z_df ['z_spec'] - z_df ['z_phot']
```

but this records only the final `y_pred`.

(Because my data will contain `NaN`s, I can't put `z_df = pd.DataFrame([])` before the loop. -- **Ignore**)

How can I achieve this?

Comment: What do NaNs have to do with you not being able to put `z_df` before the loop? If you want the dataframe to be persistent between interations, it needs to be defined outside the loop. Dumping a dataframe to disk after each iteration is also always an option.

Comment: Ok, scratch that point about NaNs; that particular problem disappears if I move train_test_split outside the loop as well. Still, the main problem persists. I'll try writing to a file and see if that works.

Comment: Hey Jim, this isn't exactly an answer: but I'd recommend against doing this. "Evaluating average model performance across multiple data splits" is generally a job for [`cross_val_score`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.cross_val_score.html) or [`KFold`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.KFold.html) if you have a more complex training method.